# How to convert DateTime Object to Date in Jquery

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

I am having trouble converting date object in dateTime in jquery.
Here are my Code

js code:

```
                html += '<tr>';
                html += '<td>' + lst[index].RowNumber + '</td>'
                html += '<td>' + lst[index].AccountCode + '</td>'
                html += '<td>' + lst[index].DepartmentName + '</td>'
                html += '<td>' + lst[index].DepartmentHead + '</td>'
                html += '<td>' + lst[index].CreatedBy + '</td>'
                html += '<td>' + lst[index].CreatedOn + '</td>'
                html += '<td>' + lst[index].ModifiedBy + '</td>'
                html += '<td>' + lst[index].LastModifiedOn + '</td>'

                html += '<td><a href="#"><span class="icon-edit" id="'
                html += lst[index].AccountCodeID
                html += '"</span></a></td> <td><a href="#"><span class="icon-delete" id="'
                html += lst[index].AccountCodeID
                html += '"</span></a></td>'
                html += '</tr>';

                $('#tblbody').html(html);
```

Property Class in C#

```
 public long AccountCodeID { get; set; }
    public String AccountCode { get; set; }
    public String DepartmentName { get; set; }
    public String DepartmentHead { get; set; }
    public int UserModuleID { get; set; }
    public int PortalID { get; set; }
    public String CreatedBy { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedOn  { get; set; }
    public DateTime LastModifiedOn { get; set; }
    public String ModifiedBy { get; set; }
```

Output
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can parse date like code below;

```
var dateObj = new Date(parseInt(lst[index].LastModifiedOn));

var formattedDate = (dateObj.getMonth() + 1) + "/" + (dateObj.getDate()+1) + "/" + dateObj.getFullYear();

lst[index].LastModifiedOn = formattedDate;
```